# How come I cannot download an image with urllib.urlretrieve?

Tags: python

I tried to download Google's logo with

```
import os, urllib
folderName = 'downloadedImages'
if not os.path.exists(folderName):
  os.makedirs(folderName)
urllib.urlretrieve(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png, './' + folderName + '/')
```

However, I receive an error: `IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: './downloadedImages/'`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of just what the error says: What you've provided in the second argument is a directory.  It needs to be the local (destination) filename.

The [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) state (emphasis mine):

> The second argument, if present, specifies the *file location* to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name).

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

You need to give the filename, not the directory path:

```
urllib.urlretrieve("path/to/resource", os.path.join(folderName, "filename.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter to `urllib.urlretrieve()` need to a file name rather than directory.